# what should be the parametric form of the l2 regularization in a Bayesian setting?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, regularized

In a Bayesian setting for parameter estimation, what should be the parametric form of the prior distribution in order to perform l2 regularization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

L2 regularization is equivalent to a Gaussian prior.

See, for example, Jason Rennie's [On L2-norm Regularization and the Gaussian Prior (2003)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.113.1049).

(For future reference, this kind of question should probably go to http://stats.stackexchange.com . . . where I see you also posted this. Don't do that.)